# App Engine blocks emails that contain too many links

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app that sends me an email every day with a list of tweets. Each tweet contains at least a link. Beginning this month, I stopped receiving the email. At first, I thought the problem was Twitter with its v1.1 API. But after rewriting my app, I noticed that it's GAE that doesn't send the email. To be more precise, it doesn't send the emails that contain multiple links. It's makes no difference if the email is html or plain text.

Did GAE change its spam rules? And if that's the case, why can't I at least send emails to myself(email address registered as administrator)?

Comment: What do your logs say?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about GAE, but you can easily avoid this issue using one of many available SMTP providers. For example, http://www.mailgun.com/ has a free plan with 200 messages per day.